# Roots Sage 10 using view Composers outside of app directory

Tags: php, wordpress, psr-4, roots-sage

For anyone who is familiar with Sage 10, I am trying to get View Composers working outside of the default `app/View/Composers` directory. I have another directory `Composers` inside the parent directory of the Sage 10 directory and loaded it in correctly through PSR-4. This is working fine.

However, it does not seem to work. I wonder if I have to register my 'custom' Composer directory somewhere, but the documentation on Sage 10 is very shallow to non-existent.

So in the parent of my Sage dir, there is a Composers dir that gets loaded though PSR-4 containing an `Application.php` which looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace Composers;

use \Roots\Acorn\View\Composer;

class Application extends Composer
{

    /**
     * List of views served by this composer.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected static $views = [
        'partials.header',
    ];

    /**
     * Data to be passed to view before rendering.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function with()
    {
        return [
            'someVar' => $this->sayHello(),
        ];
    }

    public function sayHello()
    {
        return 'Hello from Composer';
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the view composer in the view config of Sage 10 by adding (without any luck)

```
'composers' => [
    Composers\Application::class,
],
```

Does anyone know where to 'register' these custom Composers? I have to note that PSR-4 is autoloading the classes correctly.

**Edit**
The Sage 10 repository can be found here: https://github.com/roots/sage

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for this answer and figured it out. In my use case, I needed to extract data from my root `App` composer through a method I created. Similar to your `sayHello()` public function. I needed it in a PHP file outside of Sage 10's root `app` directory. It was to overwrite a plugin's (The Events Calendar) template file.

I realized, that this `App` composer was just a class object... and sage does a TON of `use` statement imports. So at the top of my PHP file I added:

```
use App\view\Composer\App
```

This loaded the class into my PHP file with no issues. Next, I attempted to use it in the following way:

```
$sageAppComposer = new App();
$globalSocialMediaNetworkLinks = $sageAppComposer->globalSocialNetworkLinks();
```

This worked! The data returned from my function was saved to `$globalSocialMediaNetworkLinks`. As a result, given your example... you could do the following:

```
use App\view\Composer\Application
$sageApplicationComposer = new Application();
echo $sageApplicationComposer->sayHello();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A response for future devs: find their discourse it's slightly better.

These are being loaded in the [Roots\Acorn\View\ViewServiceProvider](https://github.com/roots/acorn/blob/main/src/Roots/Acorn/View/ViewServiceProvider.php) class. The method checks to make sure that config array you set is associative before loading, with [Arr::isAssoc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-isassoc).

So this checks to make sure the array has keys, but it does not use them. Maybe they're relevant elsewhere... ::shrug::

```
/**
 * Attach View Composers
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function attachComposers()
{
    $composers = $this->app->config['view.composers'];

    if (is_array($composers) && Arr::isAssoc($composers)) {
        foreach ($composers as $composer) {
            $this->view()->composer($composer::views(), $composer);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```